# No display when using JSch X11 forwarding

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, x11, jsch

I'm trying to use JSch to automate a process where our users have to ssh into a particular workstation to run a GUI application (due to licensing issues). All workstations are running CentOS Linux. The process will involve a user clicking a button in a GUI application on their machine, enter their password, and the application will handle the ssh and opening the GUI application on the remote machine. I attempted my own implementation of X11 forwarding using the code; it will authenticate and connect but hang when I try and run any GUI application on the remote machine. I can run programs such as `uptime` and receive a textual response, which tells me that the ssh connection is working but X11 forwarding does not. When that didn't work, I copied and pasted the example code shown here:

```
/* -*-mode:java; c-basic-offset:2; indent-tabs-mode:nil -*- */
/**
* This program will demonstrate X11 forwarding.
*   $ CLASSPATH=.:../build javac X11Forwarding.java 
*   $ CLASSPATH=.:../build java X11Forwarding
* You will be asked username, hostname, displayname and passwd. 
* If your X server does not run at 127.0.0.1, please enter correct
* displayname. If everything works fine, you will get the shell prompt.
* Try X applications; for example, xlogo.
*
*/
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class X11Forwarding{
public static void main(String[] arg){

String xhost="127.0.0.1";
int xport=0;

try{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();  

  String host=null;
  if(arg.length>0){
    host=arg[0];
  }
  else{
    host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                     System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                     "@localhost"); 
  }
  String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
  host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

  Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

  String display=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter display name", 
                     xhost+":"+xport);
  xhost=display.substring(0, display.indexOf(':'));
  xport=Integer.parseInt(display.substring(display.indexOf(':')+1));

  session.setX11Host(xhost);
  session.setX11Port(xport+6000);

  // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
  UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
  session.setUserInfo(ui);
  session.connect();

  Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

  channel.setXForwarding(true);

  channel.setInputStream(System.in);
  channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

  channel.connect();
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
}

public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
  Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
  int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
         str,
         "Warning", 
         JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
         JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
         null, options, options[0]);
   return foo==0;
}

String passwd;
JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
public boolean promptPassword(String message){
  Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
  int result=
  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
passwd=passwordField.getText();
return true;
  }
  else{ return false; }
}
public void showMessage(String message){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
  new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                         GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                         GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                         new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
private Container panel;
public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                          String name,
                                          String instruction,
                                          String[] prompt,
                                          boolean[] echo){
  panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

  gbc.weightx = 1.0;
  gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
  gbc.gridx = 0;
  panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
  gbc.gridy++;

  gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

  JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
  for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    if(echo[i]){
      texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
    }
    else{
      texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
    }
    panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
  }

  if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                   destination+": "+name,
                                   JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
     ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
    for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
      response[i]=texts[i].getText();
    }
return response;
  }
  else{
    return null;  // cancel
  }
}
}
}
```

Again, I can connect to the remote workstation successfully through my GUI application and run textual programs such as `uptime` but no GUI applications on the remote workstation.

I can `ssh -X` into the remote workstation from a terminal window and everything works just fine.

If I run `env` on the user workstation, I see `DISPLAY=:0.0`

If I run `env` on the remote workstation while using `ssh -X`, I see `DISPLAY=localhost:11.0`

When I open the Java GUI application on the local workstation, it runs `System.out.println(System.getenv("DISPLAY"));` and it returns `:0`

When I connect to the remote system through the Java GUI application and send `env` I see `DISPLAY=localhost:11.0`

I am currently setting `user` to the current `user.name` env variable and `host` to the particular workstation with the software. `xhost` is set to 127.0.0.1 and `xport` is set to 0 (which translates to 6000 through the code). I have tried changing out the address for "localhost" with no success. I have also tried hard-coding `xport` to 0, 6000, 6001, and 6011 with no success.

I am using the Eclipse IDE but have tried both running it from the IDE and exporting a .jar and running it that way with no luck.